# grails @Resource Annotation before Domain class

Tags: grails

When I create a RESTful API in Grails, I add `@Resource(uri='env',formats=['multipart/form-data']` before the domain class. And then use `grails generate-all domain_name` to generate the controller and view.

However, in Eclipse there is an Java problem like

> The project was not built due to "RequestEnvironmentController$_on_closure51 [in [Working copy] RequestEnvironment.groovy [in test.environment.manager [in grails-app/domain [in restful-api-for-tem]]]] does not exist". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent.

Then I get rid of the annotation and the error disappears and the post method still works. I am confused, is the annotation necessary or not? If it is necessary, how can I remove the Java error?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the @Resource annotation there is no need to create a controller because this will be automatically generated as per [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/guide/webServices.html)

> Simply by adding the Resource transformation and specifying a URI,
>   your domain class will automatically be available as a REST resource
>   in either XML or JSON formats. The transformation will automatically
>   register the necessary RESTful URL mapping and create a controller
>   called BookController.